# Why next router have smaller response time than previous router in mtr?

Tags: networking, routing, router, traceroute

In other words why first host have 20.4 ms response time but second host have 15 ms response time. As I know for access to second host must pass through first host, Is that true?

Why is this happening?

```
                             My traceroute  [v0.85]
DEMON (0.0.0.0)                                        Sat Jan 17 18:49:36 2015
Resolver: Received error response 2. (server failure)er of fields   quit
                                       Packets               Pings
 Host                                Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 37.254.128.1                      0.0%  3078   77.8  20.4  11.2 319.2  23.9
 2. 10.140.129.1                      0.0%  3078   26.2  15.0  10.9 376.2  14.6
 3. 10.140.0.33                       0.0%  3077   13.1  15.2  11.1 399.7  15.5
 4. 10.140.0.18                       0.0%  3077   17.3  15.4  11.3 365.3  14.7
 5. 10.143.255.202                    0.0%  3077   13.2  17.8  11.4 337.0  23.7
 6. 217.219.0.115                    14.1%  3077  102.8  22.0  11.4 438.0  33.4
 7. 217.218.158.42                   16.9%  3077   63.4  22.5  17.5 302.5  16.3
 8. 10.201.47.222                    18.2%  3077   21.3  23.9  17.9 416.2  22.1
 9. 10.201.42.113                    18.6%  3077   20.2  22.8  18.1 275.1  17.1
10. 125.18.117.45                    14.3%  3077   86.3 114.1  71.3 386.0  34.7
11. 182.79.245.145                   16.0%  3077  327.5 364.4 315.4 621.1  37.8
12. ???
13. ae-7.pat2.dnx.yahoo.com          14.2%  3077  337.1 357.6 333.0 591.5  22.5
14. ae-6.pat1.nez.yahoo.com          16.7%  3077  394.2 340.5 332.2 662.2  18.0
    ae-5.pat2.nez.yahoo.com
15. ae-0.msr1.ne1.yahoo.com          16.5%  3077  339.0 339.7 331.7 695.3  17.1
    ae-1.msr1.ne1.yahoo.com
16. 98.138.0.19                      18.9%  3076  332.9 339.0 331.7 718.7  16.2
17. 98.138.93.15                     19.2%  3076  334.0 338.4 332.6 644.7  16.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line in the mtr output is the return time of a different packet that was sent.  It's not the same packet that went to host 1 and then host 2.

So, the answer is just that host 2 answers faster than host 1.  Obviously the network transit time to 2 has to be longer because the packet has to go through host 1 first, but the total response time for host 1 is more, apparently because host 1 is slower to answer its pings.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's simple: The first answers after 20.4 ms and the second 15ms later, after 35.4 ms total...

Comment: Thanks, I thinking the time is between my laptop and the host!, and I didn't know it's the time between previous router and next router.

Comment: I'm quite sure mtr does not show the times this way. For one, there's no guarantee that the responses will actually arrive in order, or at all – and it'll show exactly the same times for hop X regardless of whether it got a reply from X-1 or not. For another, the differences would be more or less equal, not always increasing. Finally, if the final delay was actually the _sum_ of all numbers shown, then it would mean the delay to the 17th hop was 2.4 seconds -- which is quite different from what a direct `ping` would show.